# Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 when building iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

Can't launch the app because of:

```
//this one works okay       
var getWall = VKRequest(method: "wall.get", andParameters: nil, andHttpMethod: "GET")

//this is how it should be
var getWall = VKRequest(method: "wall.get", andParameters: [VK_API_OWNER_ID: "some Int value"], andHttpMethod: "GET")
```

I looked in google and found that I need to set the architecture, I tried several times without any result, and even with this set:

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) $(ARCHS_STANDARD) arm64 armv7 armv7s x86_64 i386
```

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the error message for the file indicated.

**For example:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PuzzleInfoController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AllPuzzlesController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I found that the actual  file referenced by the error message was not included in the project navigator although it was in the project directory. After adding the PuzzleInfoController.h/.m files to the project and rebuilding then the build completed successfully.